# creating my own wordpress template returns server error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not a php developer which doesnt help here but i read an article on how to create my own template in wordpress, which i did and it worked ok when i applied the template to a page in the wordpress cms. I then wanted to make my template display the content of the richtext editor from the 'edit page' screen in the cms. i thought adding this code i found from the single.php might work:

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
  <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
  <div class="entrytext">
   <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
```

but it doesnt :( it just gives me a 'server error' page when i visit the page. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your whole file or just a portion of it? If it's the whole file, you forgot to close an if-statement and the while-loop (You opened them at the first line) by adding the following:

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ignore this its just wrong ;P**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
```

can be just

```
<?php while (have_posts()) the_post();?>
```

but i think you must use Exec-PHP

Comment: The first one is the standard WordPress-Loop, you shouldn't have to change it. What if you want to `echo` a message, if there aren't any posts? Then you'll need the if-statement!

Comment: the while wont execute if have_posts() returns false ... and theres no else so it wont echo any msg :) but true it could be used

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I said - if you want to echo a message, you'll need the if-statement.